# Como retornar o nome de uma instância de uma classe?

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis

Para não ter que ficar escrevendo manualmente os dados após uma atualização nos objetos, decidi criar um método do tipo `static` para ser acessado passando o objeto como parâmetro.

```
    public static void Relatorio(Trem trem)
    { 

        Console.WriteLine($"{trem} - PESO ATUAL:       {trem.getPesoVagao()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{trem} - PESO SUPORTADO:   {trem.getCargaMAX()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{trem} - CARGA DISPONÍVEL: {trem.CargaRestante()}");

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

[image: Como aparece e como deveria aparecer]

Isso evitaria que eu ficasse escrevendo o relatório no `Main()` sempre que fizesse uma alteração no objeto, porém o nome retornado que deveria ser "T2", está retornando como `SobrecargaDeMetodos.Trem`.

Eu chamo o método da seguinte forma passando o objeto a ser analisado como parâmetro. A parte de mostrar o resultado funciona perfeitamente, porém o nome não.

```
Trem.Relatorio(T2);
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Uma outra opcao é adicionar uma propriedade `Nome` á sua class `Trem`. Dessa forma todos os trens teriam um `Nome`

```
public class Trem{
    public string Nome{get; set;}
    //...
}
```

E, sempre que cria um trem voce atribui um nome. `var t = new Trem(){Nome = "t2"};`.
E no seu relatório usaria a respectiva propriedade:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{trem.Nome} - PESO ATUAL:       {trem.getPesoVagao()}");
//...
```

Comment: Acho que isso é muita gambiarra para resolver o problema, uma propriedade tem que ser algo que pertence ao objeto. Olhando o código sem olhar o problema, entendo que essa propriedade armazena o `Nome` de um `Trem`.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Nao entendo o motivo. No meu ponto de vista pode até ser uma das melhores opcoes para resolver o problema. A nao ser que nao faca mesmo nenhum sentido os trens terem um nome.

Comment: Então, essa é a questão, ele não quer obter o nome do trem e sim obter o nome da variável que armazena o objeto `Trem`.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Mas esse conceito nem faz sentido, uma vez que as variáveis podem ter os identificadores que eu quizer. Uma vez a variável pode-se chamar `trem` e outras vezes `t2`. Também posso ter várias variáveis que apontam para o mesmo objecto.

Comment: Exatamente, não faz sentido, mas é justamente isso que o @RamonAlmeida esta perguntando! A própria pergunta provavelmente já é uma gambiarra.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Tá. Eu vou deixar a minha resposta mesmo, Continua-me parecendo que é uma maneira lógica de resolver o problema, mesmo que nao seja "mesmo á letra" para a situacao indicada pelo AP.

Answer (score 7):

Isto é um conceito errado. Primeiro não há nome de instância, existe nome da variável. Pode até ser que neste caso um nome seja igual ao nome da variável, mas nem sempre pode representar qualquer nome em um nome de variável. Mas também há um erro de entendimento do que é uma variável. Variáveis são locais e não passam de um contexto para outro, então isto que deseja não faz sentido, na verdade o que está imprimindo nem é o que está imaginando. A solução para isto muito simples:

```
public static void Relatorio(Trem trem, string nome) {
    WriteLine($"{nome} - PESO ATUAL:       {trem.getPesoVagao()}");
```

Aí chama:

```
Trem.Relatorio(T2, "T2");
```

ou se achar que pode mudar esse nome (o que me parece algo estranho, mas enfim, não vou discutir outros possíveis erros deste *design*), pode até usar:

```
Trem.Relatorio(T2, nameof(T2));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/NameofXParam.cs).

Isto apenas garante que se o nome da variável for mudado dê um erro de compilação na passagem da *string*, assim te obriga mudar o nome ali também.

Talvez tenha outros erros conceitos nisto.